# Generate pairs of students from list of names, new pairs each week

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting

I have a list of students names, and I want to pair each student with another student every week. Obviously, students can only be in one pair each week, and students should never work with someone they already worked with previously. I can generate a list of tuples of every possible pair I can make with my list of student names, but I am struggling to take those pairs and generate lists of pairs for each week.

Comment: Share whatever you have tried so far. Always a good starting point, and is more expressive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're asking for is the [scheduling algorithm for a round robin tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm). Here's one way to implement that in Python:

```
def round_robin(n):
    if n % 2:
        raise ValueError("Can't pair an odd number of students")
    half = n // 2
    students = list(range(1, n + 1))
    for round in range(n - 1):
        students.append(students.pop(1))
        pairs = list(zip(students[:half], students[:half-1:-1]))
        print(pairs)
```

And here it is in action:

```
>>> round_robin(8)
[(1, 2), (3, 8), (4, 7), (5, 6)]
[(1, 3), (4, 2), (5, 8), (6, 7)]
[(1, 4), (5, 3), (6, 2), (7, 8)]
[(1, 5), (6, 4), (7, 3), (8, 2)]
[(1, 6), (7, 5), (8, 4), (2, 3)]
[(1, 7), (8, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4)]
[(1, 8), (2, 7), (3, 6), (4, 5)]
```